# Part of this work is done at XXX; Beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

I would like to mention that one of my collaborators had done some of the work I am presenting while at University X but has since moved to University Y.

Is there a simple way to do this with the institute command?

This is what I have currently in a MWE. Part of the work was done by author BBB at institute 1 but has since moved to institute 3.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author[Benjamin H.M. Tan]{AAA\inst{2}, BBB\inst{1,3}, \\ \textbf{Benjamin H.M. Tan}\inst{1,2}, CCC\inst{1}}
\institute[X, Y, Z]{\inst{1} University X \\ \inst{2} University Y \\ \inst{3} University Z}
\title[QWERTY]{QWERTY}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Should have thought harder about it. A footnote would suffice in this case.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} % To get symbols for footnote, used [2] as option for the dagger symbol 
\author[Benjamin H.M. Tan]{AAA\inst{2}, BBB\inst{3,},\footnote[2]{Part of this work was done at University X.} \\ \textbf{Benjamin H.M. Tan}\inst{1,2}, CCC\inst{1}}
\institute[X, Y, Z]{\inst{1} University X \\ \inst{2} University Y \\ \inst{3} University Z}
\title[QWERTY]{QWERTY}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}} % To reset the footnotes to numbers
\setcounter{footnote}{0}                        % Set counter back to 0
\end{document}
```